# using variable inside of the template tags

Tags: arrays, django, pymongo

I have below sample structure

```
'_id': 1
'company': 'XXX'
'numberOfProducts': 2
'products': [
        {'sku': 'cnx1cs', 'name': 'canon', 'qty': 3},
        {'sku': 'nkx1cs', 'name': 'nikon', 'qty': 2}
         ]
```

When I use this `{{list_of_assets.products.0.name}}` notation inside of the html file (in Django),  it seems much more comfortable instead of using `dict.items()/dict.iteritems()` especially when you think much more nested arrays.

But I could not figure out how I can control array item number inside of the for loop...

I mean if we think above sample, how can I iterate for loop two times and produce below notation by somehow using variable inside of the tag

```
    {{list_of_assets.products.0.name}}
    ....
    {{list_of_assets.products.1.name}}
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
{% for product in list_of_assets.products %}
  {{product.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django templates do not allow complicated looping structures or programming. (For full details on the template Philosophy, please read: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html section: Philosophies and Limitations.

That said, the only way to display all the items in an array is to use the solution karthikr suggested above:

```
{%for p in list_of_assets.products %}
    {{p.name}}
{% empty %}
    Nothing in the list!
{% endfor %}
```